# java rmi call discarded after remote exception thrown

Tags: java, rmi

When using rmi ,after a call to remote metod if connection betwen two computer broke and remote exception thrown ,called metod execution discarded immediately or it continue execution
until it finish ? I think it has another thread at remote machine and it continue but i am not sure ..

Comment: i realize english is probably not your first language, but you are going to have to clean this up before anyone can give you any help.  your sentences run on, you have a lot of ambiguous "it"s floating around (which is especially confusing when asking questions about distributed computing where you need to be clear which end of the connection you are talking about).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

going on my initial interpretation of your question, i *think* you are asking if the remote method call will continue on the remote computer after the connection is severed and the caller has already received an exception signalling a connection failure.

assuming that is your question, the answer is "yes".  the remote method may continue executing even though communication has been effectively lost.  in general, assuming the remote computer has read the method input successfully, it will not realize that the connection has been lost until it attempts to return the method result back to the caller (i.e. when it tries to write to the socket).